# An "OR" predicate on ViewerFilter in spite of the default "And" predicates?

Tags: java, filtering, jface, treeviewer

I am developing a RCP application which contains a `TreeViewer` and I want to activate multiple filters on it that should work with the "OR" predicates, for example :

> A
>   |--B
>   |--|--redColor
>   |--|--blueColor
>   |--C
>   |--|--greenColor

I have a filter to show the `redColor` and a filter to show the `greenColor`. but when activating these two filters together, nothing is displayed.

My filter class extends the `ViewerFilter` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a single ViewerFilter that has the "or" condition inside of it, not two separate filters.